# Remove an object by an id in mongodb and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting an error on robots.remove stating robots is not defined, But I can't possibly figure out exactly why. Please help. thank you.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/robots'); //connecting to localdb

router.delete('/:id', function(req,res){ 

    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);

    robots.remove({_id:ObjectId(id)}, function(err, result){ //undefined??
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({err: 'Error: Could not delete robot'});
        if(!result) return res.status(400).send({err: 'Robot bot deleted from firebase database'});
        console.log('deleted!!!');
        res.send(result); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Well it's a pretty consice error as I don't need `robots` being "declared" anywhere. Surely you have more code than this. You should be calling somthing like `robots = mongoose.model("robots")`, and also after an initial declaration of that model as well.

Comment: I do have a model, which contains a schema, But where can I declare it so it links to my db, I don't precisely understand where I can declare my db on the route or server.

Comment: First you "need to " declare the model, which you seemingly already have somewhere. But the specific problem here is that you have declared this in another module and therefore "must" `require` that module to import the model definition or alternately call `mongoose.model` "again" with the same model name as defined in your local scope. The error being reported is because their is no object declared in the local scope.

Comment: That fixed the robot undefined error, but not I get an error on the same line, Robot.remove({_id: mongoose.ObjectId(id)}).exec(function(err, result) Will something like this execute the code or how would I reword it. btw thanks you've been helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to load the user model first.

```
var robots  = require('../app/models/robots');//Load the model
```

robots.js file should look like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var robotSchema = mongoose.Schema({
//Your schema here
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('robots', robotSchema);
```